# Lebesgue measure of the intersection of intervals

Tags: measure-theory

If we define $E_1 = \mathbb{R}$ and for each $n \geq 2$ define $E_n = (n, \infty)$.

Would $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n)$ be zero or infinity?

Where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3):

The intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is empty, so the measure is zero.